# Non-commutativity of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{2Z}$

Tags: group-theory

We can show that a group with order $p^2$ is abelian provided that $p$ is a prime. Also $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{2Z}$ is a group with order $4=2^2$ and not cyclic. So, am I missing something? Should we assume that the prime $p$ must be greater than $2$ to have an abelian group?

Comment: $\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$ is not cyclic, but it is abelian. (Indeed, any direct product of abelian groups is abelian.) Note that all cyclic groups are abelian, but not all abelian groups are cyclic.

Comment: Oh, I see. I should take a rest.

Comment: Why do you think that the group is not abelian? If you told us, we might be able to help you see where the problem is.

Comment: I should have written "cyclic"  instead of abelian, unfortunately.

Comment: I was pretty shocked myself when I learned that the famous Klein 4 group was just $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$

Comment: To address your first sentence, note that for any prime $p$, there are (up to isomorphism) exactly two abelian groups of order $p^2$, namely $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ and $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$. The first is cyclic and the second is not. More generally, **any** finite abelian group can be expressed as the direct product of one or more cyclic groups. This is the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

Comment: Okay then, I have a related question:
How can I show that there are only 2 non-isomorphic groups of order 4?
Should I write down the Cayley tables (there are 4 of them I believe) or just say "it is isomorphic to  either $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{2Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z_4}$?

Comment: There are two possibilities if $G$ has order $4$. Either $G$ has an element of order $4$, in which case $G$ is cyclic, or it does not, in which case all of the non-identity elements have order $2$. It is a standard exercise to prove that any group whose non-identity elements all have order $2$ is abelian, and from that it's easy to show that $G$ must be the direct product of two cyclic subgroups of order $2$. Sketch of proof: let $a$ and $b$ be two non-identity elements. Then $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle b \rangle$ are normal subgroups (because $G$ is abelian) with trivial intersection.

Comment: My trial:
Let $|G|=4$, by Lagrange's theorem for any $H \leq G$, order of $H$ divides $4$. Pick some $x \in G$. If $|<x>| =4$, then $G$ is cyclic, otherwise $|<x>|=1$ or $2$. If $x$ is not the identity, then its order must be $2$.

Comment: Every non-identity element has order $2$, so how to show that $G$is abelian, let me think a little bit.

Comment: So since $x^2=1$, every element is its inverse. Thus, for any $a,b \in G$, $abab=1 \implies ba = a^{-1}b^{-1}=ab$.

Comment: @Ninja Correct.

Answer (score 2):

That group is most certainly abelian. Any direct product of abelian groups is abelian.

Comment: sure, no problem.